# Youtube api v3 shows "Access Not Configured" code:403

Tags: android, api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I created a Google application in the developers console, turned on "YouTube Data API v3", generated the server API key.But When I am passing api key In API(Webservice) It shows Error Like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "usageLimits",
            "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
            "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.",
            "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
        }],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your   API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration."
    }
}
```

How can I solve my this problem?

Comment: please, describe your project. Are you using the android sdk or not?

Comment: You have to create android key not server key with SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem, It was solved by using browser key that allows all referers..

Comment: This isn't a good solution and bypasses the entire point of limiting access.